# Multipart File upload Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, multipart

Im using Spring Boot and want to use a Controller to receive a multipart file upload.
When sending the file I keep getting the **error 415 unsupported content type** response and the controller is never reached

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary1KvzQ1rt2V1BBbb8' not supported
```

Ive tried sending using form:action in html/jsp page and also in a standalone client application which uses RestTemplate.  All attempts give the same result

`multipart/form-data;boundary=XXXXX not supported.`

It seems from multipart documentation that the boundary param has to be added to the multipart upload however this seems to not match the controller receiving `"multipart/form-data"`

My controller method is setup as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/things", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data" ,
                                     produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
     public ResponseEntity<ThingRepresentation> submitThing(HttpServletRequest request,
                                     @PathVariable("domain") String domainParam,
                                     @RequestParam(value = "type") String thingTypeParam,
                                     @RequestBody MultipartFile[] submissions) throws Exception
```

With Bean Setup

```
 @Bean
 public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
     return new MultipartConfigElement("");
 }

 @Bean
 public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
     org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver();
     multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000);
     return multipartResolver;
 }
```

As you can see I've set the consumes type to "multipart/form-data" but when the multipart is sent it must have a boundary parameter and places a random boundary string.

**Can anyone please tell me how I can either set the content type in controller to match or change my request to match my controller setup?**

My attempts to send ... 
Attempt 1...

```
<html lang="en">
<body>

    <br>
    <h2>Upload New File to this Bucket</h2>
    <form action="http://localhost:8280/appname/domains/abc/things?type=abcdef00-1111-4b38-8026-315b13dc8706" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table width="60%" border="1" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="35%"><strong>File to upload</strong></td>
                <td width="65%"><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Attempt 2....

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
parts.add("file", new FileSystemResource(pathToFile));

try{

    URI response = template.postForLocation(url, parts);
}catch(HttpClientErrorException e){
    System.out.println(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```

Attempt 3...

```
FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        formHttpMessageConverter.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF8"));


        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add( formHttpMessageConverter );
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        map.add("file", new FileSystemResource(path));

        HttpHeaders imageHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        imageHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> imageEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, imageHeaders);
        ResponseEntity e=  restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, imageEntity, Boolean.class);
        System.out.println(e.toString());
```

Comment: how did you write your domain ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
@RequestBody MultipartFile[] submissions
```

should be

```
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] submissions
```

The files are not the request body, they are part of it and there is no built-in `HttpMessageConverter` that can convert the request to an array of `MultiPartFile`.

You can also replace `HttpServletRequest` with `MultipartHttpServletRequest`, which gives you access to the headers of the individual parts.

Comment: That worked thanks.  All my client attempts now work against this fix on the server side.  Turns out that I didn't require the MultipartConfigElement and the MultipartResolver beans.  Possibly boot is creating these for me.

Answer (score 27):

You can simply use a **controller** method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

  try {
    // Handle the received file here
    // ...
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }

  return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
} // method uploadFile
```

Without any additional configurations for Spring Boot.

Using the following **html form** client side:

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="/uploadFile" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"> 
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to set **limits on files size** you can do it in the `application.properties`:

```
# File size limit
multipart.maxFileSize = 3Mb

# Total request size for a multipart/form-data
multipart.maxRequestSize = 20Mb
```

Moreover to send the file with **Ajax** take a look here:
http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/02/08/spring-boot-file-upload-with-ajax/

Answer (score 9):

Latest version of SpringBoot makes **uploading multiple files** very easy also. On the browser side you just need the standard HTML upload form, but with **multiple input elements** (one per file to upload, which is very important), all having the same element name (name="files" for the example below)

Then in your Spring @Controller class on the server **all you need** is something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> upload(
        @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] uploadFiles) throws Exception     
{
    ...now loop over all uploadFiles in the array and do what you want
  return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Those are the tricky parts. That is, knowing to create multiple input elements each named "files", and knowing to use a MultipartFile[] (array) as the request parameter are the tricky things to know, but it's just that simple. I won't get into how to process a MultipartFile entry, because there's plenty of docs on that already.

Answer (score 4):

```
   @Bean
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("5120MB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("5120MB");
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }
```

put it in class where you are defining beans

Answer (score 4):

Add `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestParam`

```
 public UploadFile upload(@RequestPart(name = "file")   MultipartFile multipartFile{
    //your code to process file
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Controller, your method should be;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<SaveResponse> uploadAttachment(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) {
....
```

Further, you need to update application.yml (or application.properties) to support maximum file size and request size.

```
spring:
    http:
        multipart:
            max-file-size: 5MB
            max-request-size: 20MB
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add/image", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity upload(@RequestParam("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)
{   
    try {
        MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest=(MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;
        Iterator<String> it=multipartRequest.getFileNames();
        MultipartFile multipart=multipartRequest.getFile(it.next());
        String fileName=id+".png";
        String imageName = fileName;

        byte[] bytes=multipart.getBytes();
        BufferedOutputStream stream= new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/static/image/book/"+fileName));;

        stream.write(bytes);
        stream.close();
        return new ResponseEntity("upload success", HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity("Upload fialed", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }   
}
```