# Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary...' not supported Spring

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

Spring 5.0.7: MVC, Data, Security. 
I configure `multipartResolver`.

I send next Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: '/api/v1/category/add',
    data: new FormData(form)
}).done(result=>{console.log(result);}).fail(result=>{
    console.error('ERROR:', result.responseJSON.httpStatus, result.responseJSON.message, result);
    self.toast.error('API Error.');
});
```

But there is an error: `Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary6xBCDjCtYYuUVR5c' not supported`

why? i don't understand why error happen.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@Secured("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1")
public class ApiController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ApiController.class);

    @PostMapping(value = "/category/add", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private Response categoryAdd(Response response, @RequestBody CategoryAddForm categoryAddForm) {
        LOGGER.info(categoryAddForm.toString());
        return response;
    }

}
```

CategoryAddForm:

```
public class CategoryAddForm {

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private MultipartFile preview;

    public CategoryAddForm() { }

    public CategoryAddForm(String name, String description, MultipartFile preview) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.preview = preview;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public MultipartFile getPreview() {
        return preview;
    }
}
```

*I do not know what else to write, but SO requires more text. (*

Comment: I just noticed, you have set contentType=false while making ajax request. Are you certain that it is correct. Maybe you need to pass `multipart/form-data` or exclude the field altogether (it may get populated with correct content type). Sorry I have not worked much with frontend, will have to try the snippet to understand more. Backend looks fine to me.

Comment: Where is this error coming from? Do you have a stacktrace on the server side? Could you share it with us? What is this Response class in your controller? Can you share the raw http request and response headers as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your controller, use @RequestParam instead of @RequestBody.

Was having the same issue and it worked for me. 
See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699727/multipart-file-upload-spring-boot) for more info

Comment: Thanks! It would be better if you would quote a bit from the relevant answer too (:

Comment: I did that already. "In your controller, use @RequestParam instead of @RequestBody" that's the solution..jst putting that as a reference

Comment: Thanks guy, you saved my day. I have a form that returned both primitive data and a file. On the Springboot side, I used "(@RequestParam Map<String, Map<Object, Object>> form,
            @RequestParam("medias") MultipartFile[] medias)" to receive it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this maven dependency `commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.x`
and declare `MultipartResolver` bean

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Above method is for Spring controllers. If you want to do for Async Spring controllers refer this article.
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload

Hope it helps!