# Java 8 SpringBoot HttpServletRequest return always -1 in InputStream

Tags: java, spring-boot, inputstream

My task is to transfer the code from the old project to the new Spring Boot project. Unfortunately i have a problem. 
In the old project, there was a servlet that worked with this code:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
      int result = request.getInputStream().read(); // result > -1 depends on the request
}
```

In a springboot project:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**")
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
      int result = request.getInputStream().read(); // always return -1
}
```

How to get the valid InputStream from HttpServletRequest in SpringBoot project?

Comment: what is the request payload?

Comment: a third-party service sends for processing data that is used in business logic on this service

Comment: Is it a JSON, a string, octet-stream?

Comment: multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

You said me your request is `multipart/form-data`. So you should rewrite the rest controller.

See the following examples:

- https://blog.classkick.com/using-multipart-form-data-with-spring-boot-3216d67ae2b9
- [Multipart File upload Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699727/multipart-file-upload-spring-boot)