# How to create RestAPI which accepts excel file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, spring-mvc

I am very new to Springboot. I need to create a rest API which accepts Excel file. I need to use the data from the excel file to perform action. I know how to create API with @RequestParam and @RequestBody, but not sure how to create one for excel file. I am not storing the file in db, so no need of model. I searched online but saw all the resources talking about uploading file through client side. I want to act on the file received in my API.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699727/multipart-file-upload-spring-boot/25700288

Comment: What you want to do when the file arrives at your API? Save on your disk? Read some data from the worksheet?

Comment: @MatheusCirillo yes i want to read data from the worksheet and use  it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you said that you want to read some values from the Workbook and use it.

[Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) can be an awesome library for that purpose.

The Apache POI XSSF component can be used for reading **.xlsx** and the HSSF component can be used for reading **.xls** (prior to 2007 version of MS Office)

You could receive your file in a `multipart/form-data` request, have Spring deserialize it to you into a `MultipartFile` object and then use Apache POI to read the `InputStream` of the file, create the Workbook and use it.

Add the Apache POI XSSF Maven dependency to your project:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Example in a Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/my-controller")
public class MyController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);

    @PostMapping(consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handlePost(@RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile file) {
        // validate that the file has the .xlsx extension (which doesn't mean much, actually..)
        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        if (fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 5, fileName.length()).equals(".xlsx")) {
            try (InputStream excelIs = file.getInputStream()) {
                // create the Workbook using the InputStream returned by 
                // MultipartFile#getInputStream()
                Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(excelIs); 
                // get the first sheet of the Workbook
                Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); 

                Iterator<Row> rowIt = sheet.rowIterator();
                // iterating rows..
                while (rowIt.hasNext()) { 
                    Row currentRow = rowIt.next();
                    // as an example, i'm getting the string value of 
                    // the first cell in the current iteration
                    String firstCellStringValue = currentRow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

                    log.info("{} is the value of the 1st cell in the {} row", firstCellStringValue, currentRow.getRowNum() + 1); // need to do + 1 cause the index starts at zero..
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                // .. nothing to do, you could rethrow a custom exception or 
                // add throws declaration
                throw new CustomException("Failed to process");
            }

        } else {
            throw new CustomException("The file should be a .xlsx");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(...); // your return
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Excel format can be a real pain to handle.

But if you want, you can try the Apache POI library. In particular the spreadsheet module: http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/

Here's an example how to use it (caution: the example doesn't use the most recent POI version. Though maybe some parts have changed in the meantime): https://mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/